# Java Looping string replacemnet

Tags: java

I want this part of my code for my calculator and since I am replacing x with the variable I need to made sure something like 2x is 2*x. Why is this code adding a '*' when there is a + in front?
if pLine = "1+x";

Why does it still add a "*"?

```
for (int j = 0; j < pLine.length(); j++)
    {   
        if (pLine.charAt(j) == 'X' || pLine.charAt(j) == 'x' )
        {
            if(pLine.charAt(j-1) != '+' || pLine.charAt(j-1) != '-' || pLine.charAt(j-1) != '/' || pLine.charAt(j-1) != '*')
                {

                pLine = pLine.substring(0, j) + "*" + pLine.substring(j, pLine.length());
                System.out.println(pLine.substring(0, j));
                break;



                 }
            else
            {

            }


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the boolean logic incorrect in this line

```
if (pLine.charAt(j-1) != '+' || pLine.charAt(j-1) != '-' || pLine.charAt(j-1) != '/' || pLine.charAt(j-1) != '*')
```

This statement will always be true, because no matter what that character is, it will either be not equal to `'+'` or it will be not equal to `'-'`.

It should be this:

```
char c = pLine.charAt(j-1);
if (!(c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '/' || c == '*'))
```

Or this:

```
if (c != '+' && c != '-' && c != '/' && c != '*')
```

Read about [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) for more explanation on why these two expressions are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

In the following line:

```
if(pLine.charAt(j-1) != '+' || pLine.charAt(j-1) != '-' || pLine.charAt(j-1) != '/' || pLine.charAt(j-1) != '*')
```

You should have `&&` instead of `||`.